# Sorting apex:pageblocktable

Tags: apex, pageblocktable, datatable, sort

I was wondering if someone has used the PageBlockTableEnhancerADV plugin and was able to implement sorting function for each column.

I was trying to use the www.datatable.com sorting plugin but I can make it work.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks

This is what I have:

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {

     jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "numeric-comma-pre": function (a) {
            // prepare number
            a = +(a.replace(",", "."));
            a = (isNaN(a)) ? Number.MAX_VALUE : a;
            return a;
        },
        "numeric-comma-asc": function (a, b) {
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
        },
        "numeric-comma-desc": function (a, b) {
            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
        }
       });




          //add datetable to mid
          $('[id$="j_id0:j_id12:j_id62:mid"]').dataTable();

          var table =  $('[id$="j_id0:j_id12:j_id62:mid"]').DataTable({ 

                                         "aoColumnDefs": [
                                                            { "sType": "numeric-comma", "aTargets": [3,4,5,6,10,11,12,13] }
                                         ]

                                         });
          new $.fn.dataTable.ColReorder( table );


      } );

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps in this [link](http://funwithsfdc.blogspot.com/2013/10/jquery-tablesorter-meets.html) to fix the sorting on `apex:pageblocktable`.

It uses the [jQuery tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/) to sort the table client-side.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" tabStyle="Opportunity" extensions="myext" id="thepage">
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'jquery.tablesorter.min.js')}"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $j = jQuery.noConflict();    
        $j(document).ready(function () {
        $j("[id$=theaddrs]").tablesorter();
        });    
    </script>

    <apex:pageBlock id="theaddrsblock">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Addrs}" var="a" id="theaddrs" styleClass="tablesorter" headerClass="header">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:outputText styleClass="header" value="{!$ObjectType.Address__c.Fields.Street__c.Label}" />
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!a.Street__c}" />
            </apex:column>
        <!-- the other columns, closing tags, and that's it -->
```

Comment: sf.dev, thank you for your response! I will try your solution and let you know.

Comment: Thank you so much, this plugin works like charm. I really appreciate it! you just made my day :)