# Visualforce page - standard controller account - sort table

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, tablesorter

do you know how to sort data in an apex:pageBlockTable in a simple way (i am starting visualforce developments).

I use the standard account controller for this page.
Thanks!

here is an example, i want to sort the related opportunities for this VF page generated via a button from every SF account:

```
 <apex:pageBlock >  
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunities" collapsible="false">
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.opportunities}" var="opportunity" border="1px solid black" cellpadding="3" rowClasses="alldatarows">
           <apex:column value="{!opportunity.StageName}" style="padding: 7px;order-bottom: 1px solid ddd;border: 1px solid black;"/>
           <apex:column value="{!opportunity.Amount}" style="padding: 7px;order-bottom: 1px solid ddd;border: 1px solid black;"/>
           <apex:column value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}" style="padding: 7px;order-bottom: 1px solid ddd;border: 1px solid black;"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: You will need either JavaScript or Apex. You can't sort using only the standard controller.

Comment: Personally, I recommend against investing time learning Visaulforce. Its use cases at this point are fairly niche. Learn `Lightning Web Components` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please check Jquery based approaches
Refer the link below. As Adrian mentioned on the comment a better approach is LWC.
[Sorting apex:pageblocktable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79587/sorting-apexpageblocktable)